# Rename and exchange multiple shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile

In a project in which I am using a specific shapefile with data from a specific date multiple times (around 100 times) with different legends each time, every few months, I save the shapefile with new data, and hence have my maps updated.

I now want to keep the old data still available and am looking for a way, in which I can easily exchange the one shapefile I use multiple times in one project, in one batch, so as not having to change it 100 times.

I am using QGIS 2.14.14 Essen.

Comment: Could you add information relating to the software you are using?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.14.14-Essen.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this properly...

Assuming you have a shapefile file called myshapefile... Right-click myshapefile in the layer panel and save as "myshapefile-historic".

You should now have myshapefile and myshapefile-historic.

Then enter the new data in myshapefile. As this is the file already referenced 100 times by the project, 1 change should be reflected in all the layer duplicates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. that is kind of how I did things before. however I am looking for a way to keep the historic data in a project as well. Ideally I would exchange in one batch, all myshapefile in the project with myshapefile-historic, and save them in a seperate project-historic. is that in any way possible in QGIS? I tried to explore how this could be done in the project text file, but all shapefiles there seem to be referenced not only with their filename but also with a number, that changes, so I don't know how I could do a find and replace operation there. would anybody know?

Comment: Does the geometry change, or just the attributes?

Comment: no, the geometry does not change, just the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As your geometry does not change, I would recommend that you use a shapefile to keep your geometries and a separate csv table to keep your attributes. You would have an id column in both tables that match so that a relationship can be defined in QGIS to join the tables.

This way each time you add a new line in the csv, it will automatically be joined to the feature in your shapefile with the corresponding id. See the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#id21) for a full explanation on 1-N relationships.